# Openshift multiple route statefulness using single cookie not working

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, session-cookies, kubernetes-ingress

I am creating routes using Ingress in openshift cluster for our application and want to achieve sticky session using "router.openshift.io/cookie_name". In the application we have two sub application running in same pod different container(different ports). In the application we can redirect from example.com/ABC to example.com/XYZ and it should be in same session.

Below is ingress configuration-

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-gui
  annotations:
    router.openshift.io/cookie_name: "sessionIdIngress"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: http://example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ABC
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  number: 8080

          - path: /XYZ
            pathType:
                Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

The session stickiness using "sessionIdIngress" works fine when I am on application "/ABC" But it didn't work on "/XYZ" as different sessionId is created for this Route.

Is their a way to have same sessionId created by Ingress for both Routes ?